# stream with ffserver without encode-decode

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, streaming

I have static file on my disk I want to stream it with ffserver .

The problem is that ffserver is decode and encode my file.

I know how to pass decode and encode when I save stream to file `ffmpeg-i http://.... -c:v copy test.avi`.

How can I do that when I stream with ffserver with command `ffmpeg -i test.avi http://<ffserverUrl>`

`ffmpeg -i test.264 -c:v copy http://<ffserverUrl>` still re-encode the video

I know that ffserver is not recommended but I need this option please

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried doing a stream copy? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @MichaelLiebman ffmpeg -i test.264 -c:v copy http://<ffserverUrl>  still re-encode the video

Comment: @resfds - if you have related follow-up questions, please ask them as new questions, not in comments.

Answer (score 3):

FFmpeg, by default, uses ffserver's conf file to set encoding parameters. 
Add `-override_ffserver` to the ffmpeg command to prevent that.